# UL and menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get my ul for MAINTENANCE to show up and have specified classes in my css style sheet to be referenced i know there working as there in use elsewhere but for some reason my sub menu for MAINTENANCE isnt showing up any ideas?

```js
/*
 * Superfish v1.4.8 - jQuery menu widget
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * CHANGELOG: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/changelog.txt
 */

;(function($){
  $.fn.superfish = function(op){

    var sf = $.fn.superfish,
        c = sf.c,
        $arrow = $(['<span class="',c.arrowClass,'"> &#187;</span>'].join('')),
        over = function(){
          var $$ = $(this), menu = getMenu($$);
          clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
          $$.showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();
        },
        out = function(){
          var $$ = $(this), menu = getMenu($$), o = sf.op;
          clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
          menu.sfTimer=setTimeout(function(){
            o.retainPath=($.inArray($$[0],o.$path)>-1);
            $$.hideSuperfishUl();
            if (o.$path.length && $$.parents(['li.',o.hoverClass].join('')).length<1){over.call(o.$path);}
          },o.delay); 
        },
        getMenu = function($menu){
          var menu = $menu.parents(['ul.',c.menuClass,':first'].join(''))[0];
          sf.op = sf.o[menu.serial];
          return menu;
        },
        addArrow = function($a){ $a.addClass(c.anchorClass).append($arrow.clone()); };

    return this.each(function() {
      var s = this.serial = sf.o.length;
      var o = $.extend({},sf.defaults,op);
      o.$path = $('li.'+o.pathClass,this).slice(0,o.pathLevels).each(function(){
        $(this).addClass([o.hoverClass,c.bcClass].join(' '))
        .filter('li:has(ul)').removeClass(o.pathClass);
      });
      sf.o[s] = sf.op = o;

      $('li:has(ul)',this)[($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) ? 'hoverIntent' : 'hover'](over,out).each(function() {
        if (o.autoArrows) addArrow( $('>a:first-child',this) );
      })
      .not('.'+c.bcClass)
      .hideSuperfishUl();

      var $a = $('a',this);
      $a.each(function(i){
        var $li = $a.eq(i).parents('li');
      });
      o.onInit.call(this);

    }).each(function() {
      var menuClasses = [c.menuClass];
      if (sf.op.dropShadows  && !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7)) menuClasses.push(c.shadowClass);
      $(this).addClass(menuClasses.join(' '));
    });
  };

  var sf = $.fn.superfish;
  sf.o = [];
  sf.op = {};
  sf.IE7fix = function(){
    var o = sf.op;
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6 && o.dropShadows && o.animation.opacity!=undefined)
      this.toggleClass(sf.c.shadowClass+'-off');
  };
  sf.c = {
    bcClass     : 'sf-breadcrumb',
    menuClass   : 'sf-js-enabled',
    anchorClass : 'sf-with-ul',
    arrowClass  : 'sf-sub-indicator',
    shadowClass : 'sf-shadow'
  };
  sf.defaults = {
    hoverClass : 'sfHover',
    pathClass : 'overideThisToUse',
    pathLevels : 2,
    delay  : 1000,
    animation : {height:'show'},
    speed  : 'normal',
    autoArrows : true,
    dropShadows : false,
    disableHI : false,  // true disables hoverIntent detection
    onInit  : function(){}, // callback functions
    onBeforeShow: function(){},
    onShow  : function(){},
    onHide  : function(){}
  };
  $.fn.extend({
    hideSuperfishUl : function(){
      var o = sf.op,
          not = (o.retainPath===true) ? o.$path : '';
      o.retainPath = false;
      var $ul = $(['li.',o.hoverClass].join(''),this).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass)
      .find('>ul').hide();
      o.onHide.call($ul);
      return this;
    },
    showSuperfishUl : function(){
      var o = sf.op,
          sh = sf.c.shadowClass+'-off',
          $ul = this.not('.accorChild').addClass(o.hoverClass)
      .find('>ul:hidden');
      sf.IE7fix.call($ul);
      o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
      $ul.animate(o.animation,o.speed,function(){ sf.IE7fix.call($ul); o.onShow.call($ul); });
      return this;
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
/*---------------------*/
$(function(){
  $('.sf-menu').superfish()
})
```

```css
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
  line-height: 1.0;
}
.sf-menu ul li {
  width: 236px;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
  visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
  left: -22px;
  top: 39px; /* match top ul list item height */
  z-index: 99;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
  top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
  left: 10em; /* match ul width */
  top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
  top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
  left: 10em; /* match ul width */
  top: 0;
}

/*** STYLIZATION ***/
.sf-menu > li {
  margin: 0 13px 0 14px;
  margin-top:18px;
  margin-bottom:19px;
}
.sf-menu > li:first-child {
  margin-left:3px;
}
.sf-menu > li > a {
  font: 700 16px/20px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #757474;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.sf-menu > li > a:hover, .sf-menu > li.active > a, .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a {
  color: #242424;
}
.sf-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  width: 238px;
  padding: 0;
}
.sf-menu li li a {
  font: 11px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #efefef !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.sf-menu  li li a:hover, .sf-menu > li li.active a, .sf-menu > li li.sfHover > a {
  color: #e5e5e5;
  background: #2c2c2c !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-left: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  border-right: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
}

.sf-sub-indicator {
  display:none;
}

/* MEDIA
========================================================================= */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sf-menu{float:none;}
  .sf-menu ul,.sf-menu ul ul {min-width:100%;position: relative; left: 0 !important; top:0px !important; padding:0;background:none;}
  .sf-menu li {float:none; margin:0;}
  .sf-menu li:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
  }

  .sf-menu li a {
    line-height:54px;
    padding:0 22px;
  }
  .sf-menu > li {
    background: url('../images/480-bg-1.png') repeat-x;
  }
  .sf-menu > li+li {
    background: url('../images/480-bg-2.png') repeat-x;
  }
  .sf-menu > li+li+li {
    background: #fafafa url('../images/480-bg-3.png') repeat-x;
  }
  .sf-menu > li+li+li+li {
    background: #ebebeb url('../images/480-bg-4.png') repeat-x;
  }
  .sf-menu > li+li+li+li+li {
    background: #cccccc url('../images/480-bg-5.png') repeat-x;
  }
  .sf-menu > li+li+li+li+li+li {
    background: #bebebe url('../images/480-bg-6.png') repeat-x;
  }
  .sf-menu li li {
    width:100%;
  }
  .sf-menu  li li a:hover, .sf-menu > li li.active a, .sf-menu > li li.sfHover a {
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
  }
  .sf-menu li li a {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:30px;
    padding-left:40px;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
  }
  div.row-2 {
    background:none;
  }
  .sf-sub-indicator {
    text-indent: -999em;
    width: 3px;
    height: 6px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: url('../images/sf-sub-indicator.png') no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    left:6px;
    top:24px;
  }
  .sf-menu > li > a:hover .sf-sub-indicator, .sf-menu > li.active > a .sf-sub-indicator, .sf-menu > li.sfHover > a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: url('../images/sf-sub-indicator.png') no-repeat 0 -6px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

}
```

```html
<!-- start menu -->
<nav>
  <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-1.html">About</a></li>
    <li class=""><a class="sf-with-ul" href="index-2.html">MAINTENANCE
      <span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
      <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">- Complete Computer Diagnostics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">- Complete Safety Analysis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">- Drivability Problems</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">- Tune-ups</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">- Oil Changes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index-3.html">REPAIR</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-4.html">PRICE LIST</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-5.html">LOCATIONS</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
<!-- end menu -->
```

Comment: Isn't show how? Can you show us a fiddle? or Javascript code(assume)

Comment: The UL has inline style: `style="display: none;"` which has to be overwritten or removed. If you can't remove it make sure to use `!important` as inline style has a higher specificity than pure CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

The line

`<ul style="display: none;">`

will make this object "invisible". Try replacing it with

`<ul>`

You can also use Javascript to be able to "toggle" whether the items are visible or not.

Comment: thank you so much I can't believe i overlooked that.